# How to post data on API Nextjs server

Tags: react-native, api, next.js, fetch-api

here is my config file on server

```js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
  res.status(200).send({ message: 'waiting for Post request' })
  return
} else {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doef' })}
}
```

i dont know how to config this to receive data from my React-native application using Fetch(post).
here are my application codes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://nextjs-farzadoo.vercel.app/api/hello', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
          name: "John",
          email: "john@example.com"
  })
  })
```

Comment: Try to describe what you expect to happen, and what's really happening.

Comment: see this example for how use fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data